# while inserting values in a table through JDBC java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException:

Tags: oracle, jdbc, ojdbc

getting this error for the below code
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.main(OracleSql.java:1717)

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Z1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
    
        // String query = "select * from Employee";
        //String sql = "CREATE TABLE people(\r\n"+ "id INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,\r\n"+ "name VARCHAR2(50) \r\n"+ ");";
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        //Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"); 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:","system","palak");
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        String sql = "insert into test1 values(100)";
        stmt.execute(sql);
        
        System.out.println("dOne");
}
}
```

Comment: You're executing the wrong program. You seem to be executing a program included in the Oracle JDBC driver (`oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql`), which expects a commandline argument, instead of your own program (`Z1`).

Comment: No actually that is only the original code, the other lines are commented

Comment: You can [edit] your question to show us (a) the full stack trace of the error you are getting; and (b) the command you are using to run your program. And as an extra check, you can add a print statement at the start of your code: `System.out.println("My code has started...");` - just to prove to yourself that you really are running the code provided in the question.

Comment: The stack trace of the exception shows that the program you run is `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql.main`, which means you're running `oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleSql`, and not your own application.

Comment: @Mark Rotteveel is correct. OracleSql.main is a test tool for the SQL scanner built into OracleDatabase JDBC. It is not supported in any way. You can try to use it to see how the driver modifies your SQL, doing things like replacing ? with :foo, replacing JDBC escape sequences, etc.